# How is the default bar legend of GeoRegionValuePlot defined?

Tags: color, legending, geographics

I want to modify the default bar legend of `GeoRegionValuePlot` but I can't find any documentation on how it is defined. Is it possible to get the default legend from a combination of options like `PlotLegends`, `ColorFunction`, and `ColorFunctionScaling`? For example, how can I get the default legend but with a certain maximum value instead of an automatic maximum value that depends on the data?

Comment: "For example, how can I get the default legend but with a certain maximum value instead of an automatic maximum value that depends on the data?"
For this, you can use `PlotRange` on the `GeoRegionValuePlot`.

Comment: I tried `PlotRange`. It doesn't set the maximum value on the bar legend.

Comment: Really? `GeoRegionValuePlot[
 EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "DepositInterestRate", 
 PlotRange -> {0, 5}]` seems to work correctly? I'm probably misunderstanding you, sorry about that!

Comment: That doesn't always work. With `PlotRange -> {0, 40}` in your example, the maximum value on the bar legend is 30, not 40. I need more control than `PlotRange` seems to provide.

Comment: Aha, I see. The Documentation for `GeoRegionValuePlot` does give examples for changing the legend with `PlotLegend`, that may help!

Answer (score 3):

`ColorFunctionBinning[{min,max,d}]` did it for me.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/107171)